# SQL Server 2005 - Rows to Cols

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table CSFT_SuggestionItem with cols like:

```
SuggestionItemID  Title                Description, etc. 
------------------------------------------------------------
1                 Item 1               Do more work
2                 Item 2               I think more is good
```

For each SuggestionItem, there can by multiple "Applications" where it can be associated, so I have CSFT_SuggestionItemApplication

```
SuggestionItemID    ApplicationID
----------------------------------
1                    1
1                    2
2                    1
```

And I have an CSFT_Application Table

```
ApplicationID        Description
----------------------------------
1                    Spring
2                    Summer
3                    Fall
4                    Winter
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
SuggestionItemID     Applications
----------------------------------
1                    Spring, Summer  
2                    Spring
```

I know I can do this by Looping. But, is there a better way in Sql server 2005? Maybe COALESCE, PIVOT, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       sia.SuggestionItemID,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ a.description
                FROM CSFT_Application a
                JOIN CSFT_SuggestionItemApplication b ON b.applicationid = a.applicationid
               WHERE b.suggestionitemid = sia.suggestionitemid
            GROUP BY a.description
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS applications
  FROM CSFT_SuggestionItemApplication sia
```

Alternate using `GROUP BY`:

```
  SELECT sia.SuggestionItemID,
         STUFF((SELECT ','+ a.description
                  FROM CSFT_Application a
                  JOIN CSFT_SuggestionItemApplication b ON b.applicationid = a.applicationid
                 WHERE b.suggestionitemid = sia.suggestionitemid
              GROUP BY a.description
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS applications
    FROM CSFT_SuggestionItemApplication sia
GROUP BY sia.SuggestionItemID
```

Comment: that doesn't work. It returns 2 rows for SuggestionItemID = 1. Maybe, the group by needs to be different???

Comment: @Patrick From An IBank: It'd return two rows for `SuggestionItemID = 1` if you forgot the `DISTINCT`

Comment: That didn't work. Here let me provide the real table names:

SELECT DISTINCT 
sia.SuggestionItemID,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ a.description 
                FROM CSFT_Application a 
           WHERE a.applicationid = sia.ApplicationID 
            GROUP BY a.description 
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS CSFT_Application 
  FROM CSFT_SuggestionItemApplication sia

Comment: @Patrick From An IBank: I updated based on your table name updates, but the table names aren't responsible for duplication.  If you're not running the query as-is, and including a column that can be more than one unique value -- this will cause the output you're seeing.  **PS**: Mind deleting your comment about the real table names?  Click the red X at the end of your comment, after your username & timestamp

Comment: Your right. I'm not running the what you have. I would get an error "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'." I think it is because there is a comma missing from: SELECT sia.SuggestionItemID,

Comment: @Patrick From An IBank: Thx, yes - my typo on the missing comma, sorry.  Try now

Comment: @Patrick From An IBank: I can't see how that's possible based on the data provided, but I won't be able to recreate in my environment for testing for an hour or so.

Comment: @Patrick From An IBank: My apologies, you were correct that the original query returned duplicate rows with incorrect information.  I've tested, and corrected my queries - see the updates.  Thanks again for your patience.